# Finding functions $h$ satisfying $h(h(n))+h(n+1) = n+2$ for all natural $n$. Why does the Golden Ratio appear?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, contest-math, functional-equations, golden-ratio

> Find all functions $h$, on natural numbers satisfying the functional relation,
> $$h(h(n))+h(n+1) = n+2$$
> for $n$ being a natural number.

**Answer**: So, the function is $h(n) = [n\alpha]-n+1$ where $\alpha$ is the golden ratio.

**Doubt**:
In the solution,the author goes backwards,i.e they already assume it and try to prove that it is true.

But what I need is an alternate solution where we discover that the function has this golden ratio in it.

There solution is like not even intuitive.

Comment: Please link to the solution you are speaking of, or provide it here.

Comment: Also:  Please edit to include your efforts.  A natural start might be to compute $h(n)$ for small $n$.

Comment: well, $h(n) $ is evidently required to be a natural number. Next, $h(n+1) < n+2$  so $h(n+1) \leq n+1.$  Still some question of what $h(1)$  might be, so experiment. Note their answer is $ \left\lfloor n (\alpha - 1) +1 \right\rfloor$  and nondecreasing.

Comment: @lulu The solution is 2-3 pages, can send images though.I just calculated $h(n)$ upto 15 to try and get some pattern to guess the function but failed.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $h(n) = an + b$.  Then the equation becomes:

$$a(an + b) + b + a(n + 1) = n + 2$$
$$a^2n + ab + b + an + a = n + 2$$
$$(a^2 + a - 1)n + ab + a + b - 2 = 0$$

For this to be satisfied for all $n$, we need the coefficient $a^2 + a - 1$ to be equal to zero.  By the quadratic formula,

$$a = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$$

Equivalently, $a \in \{ \phi - 1, -\phi \}$, where $\phi = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$ is the golden ratio.

Solving for the constant term $b$ using $ab + a + b - 2 = 0$ gives:

$$a = \frac{-1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} = \phi - 1 \implies b = -2 + \sqrt{5} \approx 0.236068$$
$$a = \frac{-1 - \sqrt{5}}{2} = -\phi \implies b = \frac{-3 - 5\sqrt{5}}{2} \approx -7.09017$$

So, the potential solutions to the equation are:

$$h(n) = (\phi - 1)n - 2 + \sqrt{5}$$
$$h(n) = -\phi n - \frac{3 + 5\sqrt{5}}{2}$$

But not really, because $n$ is constrained to be an integer, so we need $h(n)$ to also be an integer so that $h(h(n))$ is defined.  Hence, instead of having a pure linear polynomial, we get one with a ceiling operation.  I'll leave making that adjustment as an exercise for the reader.

Point is, the $\phi$ comes in because of the equation $a^2 + a - 1 = 0$ mentioned above.

Comment: Wouldn’t we have to show $h(n)$ is linear?

Comment: @Krave37: Yes, you should.  I'm hand-waving here.

Comment: How should I try to get the correct ceil, given there are two $h(n)$

Comment: I am thinking of trying to balance the $hh(n) +h(n+1)$ and get $h(n)$ to be natural.

Comment: @Krave37: If you assume that $h$'s domain and range are non-negative (per the usual definition of "natural" numbers), the one with a $-\phi$ coefficient is ruled out.

Comment: I am not able to solve it.